# How does a jQuery plugin load a collection of elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm not sure if this is a stackoverflow question since it is kind of general so forgive me if it is.

Lets say I have the following markup:

```
<div class="plugin"> ... </div>
<div class="plugin"> ... </div>
<div class="plugin"> ... </div>
```

And I wan't to run a jquery plugin and pass it every element that has the `plugin` class:

```
$(".plugin").myPlugin();
```

Plugin code looks something like this:

```
;(function ( $, window, undefined ) {

  var myPlugin = 'myPlugin',
      document = window.document,
      defaults = {
        propertyName: "value"
      };

  // The actual plugin constructor
  function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;

    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = myPlugin;

    this.init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype.init = function () {

  };

  // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor, 
  // preventing against multiple instantiations
  $.fn[myPlugin] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + myPlugin)) {
        $.data(this, 'plugin_' + myPlugin, new Plugin( this, options ));
      }
    });
  }
}(jQuery, window));
```

When I run this code it looks like the plugin constructor is being called for each element that has the class name of `myPlugin`. I thought that it would run the plugin on the entire collection of divs and only call the constructor once.

So how does it work?
Is an instance of the plugin created for each of the elements returned by the class selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is an instance of the plugin created for each of the elements returned
>   by the class selector?

**Yes**. Because you are looping through the elements when you call `this.each` inside the plugin constructor and initializing a new `Plugin` constructor for each element.

If you want to run a single custom constructor for the collection, don’t do `this.each`, just pass `this` to the `Plugin` constructor (although you might have to re-think the "caching" of the plugin using `jQuery.data`)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe following comments will help:

```
$.fn[myPlugin] = function ( options ) {
    /* "this" is collection of elements from selector*/
    return this.each(function () {
        /* "this" is individual element due to being inside "each" loop*/
      if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + myPlugin)) {
        $.data(this, 'plugin_' + myPlugin, new Plugin( this, options ));
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the top

```
$(".plugin").myPlugin();
```

**jquery selector**

jQuery will take the selector `.plugin` and then run its usual selection process, generating a jQuery object (with the jQuery prototype available for chaining) which also contains the length of the results, an array of the results, and the selector used.

so, `$(".plugin")` returns this object with the aforementioned contents.

**myPlugin()**

`myPlugin()` is a function call. It is made against the jQuery prototype which was returned from `$(".plugin")`. This function is located where it was defined: `$.fn[myPlugin]`. `fn` is jQuery's way of adding in functionality to its base prototype. Note that this is only called *once*.

**$.fn[myPlugin] = function**

The function called here now runs. It runs on `this`, which was the original jQuery object mentioned above (including the array of results from the selector). `this.each(function () {...}`, where jQuery's `each` function will iterate through the results from the jQuery object. In the case of your example, there are 3 divs.

**each iteration runs**

```
if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + myPlugin)) {
 $.data(this, 'plugin_' + myPlugin, new Plugin( this, options ));
}
```

The first line is a conditional statement which looks to see if the data object named "plugin_myPlugin" (myPlugin is a constant string value) exists on the current element (which is one of those 3 divs). None of them has this when this code is ran first.

**$.data(this, 'plugin_' + myPlugin, new Plugin( this, options ));**

This line of code takes the `this` object, which is the current html element, passes it to jQuery's `data` method, which adds an object to the element indexed by the name. The name in this case is "plugin_myPlugin", and the object is...

**new Plugin( this, options )**

Plugin is a function defined locally to the `$.fn[myPlugin]` scope in your example. It is defined as `function Plugin( element, options ) {...}`.

**function Plugin( element, options ){...}**

This function will take an element, which was passed from the iteration in `each` - in this example one of the 3 divs - and the options which were originally sent in as an argument for `$.fn[myPlugin]` (in this case there were none passed in, as can be seen with `myPlugin()`.

The function takes these arguments, and builds them onto the current Function object using `this.element`, `this.options`, `this._defaults`, and `this._name`, and then calls the init function (which is empty here).

After all that a Function object is constructed, and then is attached using jQuery's `data` method to the current element.

**Executive Summary**

The extended function `myPlugin` will run once for each element in the jQuery object generated from the selector used. The extended function creates a new Function object from the defined function `Plugin` for each element eligible (thus running the constructor on each one, 3 times in this exact example).